# send to different email based on user selection php mailer if statment?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a php mailer that uses emails like this:

```
$mail->AddAddress('example@email.com');
```

to send to all emails. What i want to do is create a drop down that has different locations. and based on what location a user selects would send it to different emails for example if a user choose west in a drop down it would send email to west@email.com or if they choose east it would send to east@email.com is it possible to use a drop down and and If statement to achieve this?

```
<div id="contact_contact">PREFERRED CONTACT:<br>
<select class="element select medium" id="element_5" name="preferred">
<option value="east" >east</option>
<option value="west" >west</option>
<option value="north" >north</option>
<option value="south" >south</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: `if ($_POST['preferred'] == "east") { $mail->AddAddress('east@email.com'); }` something like this you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you already tried that?

Comment: no i didnt even know if it was possible i wanted to ask first b4 i tried to code it

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
switch($_POST['preferred']){

case "east": $toAdd = "east@email.com"; break;
case "west": $toAdd = "west@email.com"; break;

}

$mail->AddAddress($toAdd);
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it - do not allow user-submitted arbitrary addresses, or you're opening yourself up to becoing a spam gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value posted from the form and concatenate `@email.com` to the value.

Code snippet:

```
$preferred = $_REQUEST['preferred'];
$email = $preferred.'@email.com';
$mail->AddAddress($email);
```

Depending on your form method, you can also use `$_POST or $_GET` in place of `$_REQUEST`